# What are the windows system font specifications

Tags: winapi, fonts

I'm currently trying to re-size the font of an application based on it's current font, in order to do that I was going to use `WM_GETFONT` to get the font and re-size it with an equation using the width and height of the font for input, the problem is it's return value is the system font and I don't know the specifications for that font.

Can anyone tell me how to get the specifications for the system font? Does the system font differ between OS's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve a [`LOGFONT`structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037.aspx) for an `HFONT` using the following code:

```
LOGFONT lf = { 0 };
::GetObject( hFont, sizeof( lf ), &lf );
```

With that you have all the information you need and can change just the parts you want to. To get an `HFONT` back you would use [`CreateFontIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183500.aspx):

```
HFONT hFontCustom = ::CreateFontIndirect( &lf );
```

Instead of using `WM_GETFONT` you could also consider using [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) to retrieve a [`NONCLIENTMETRICS` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729175.aspx) that already has `LOGFONT` structures you can copy, modify, and use with [`CreateFontIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183500.aspx) as illustrated above.

As for your second question, the font setting is a per user setting so it can be different even on the same installation with two different users logged on.